# Adding behavior to wcf basichttp in biztalk 2006R2

Tags: wcf, biztalk, behavior, biztalk2006r2

I am using a wcf basichttp adapter in biztalk using ESB guidance 1.0
i made a test without biztalk involved calling an asmx service and i ended up with this configuration file :

```
<behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
     <behavior name="NtlmEndpointBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
       <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
       <httpDigest impersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
      </clientCredentials>
     </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="http://address" behaviorConfiguration="NtlmEndpointBehavior"
binding="basicHttpBinding" 
bindingConfiguration="ApiSoap"
          contract="API.ApiSoap" name="ApiSoap" />
   </client>
```

Now i have to add the behavior in the wcf basichttp dynamic port i am creatin.
According to the spec i read when trying to add behavior to basichttp send port this cannot be done but on my dot net project i made it
is it a limit of biztalk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently you cant add behaviors to the adapters released with ESB guidance 1.0 due to lack of wrapper for wcf-custom adapter for biztalk 2006

Answer (score 2):

You can add behaviors to WCF ports in BizTalk, but only if you use the WCF-Custom adapter, however. It's a bit of a downside, but well, the WCF-Custom adapter is pretty much a superset of all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Use WCF-Custom wtih Http binding, then you can add whatever custom behaviors you want. I am currently doing this on a project i am working on without any problem at all.

There should be no (discernable / visible) difference between WCF-Custom on Http binding and BasicHttp except that you get far greater control when using the custom adapter.

Comment: The problem is that i am calling the WCF using the ESB guidance
and the ESB guidance 1.0 comes with 2 wrappers :
WCF-Basic and WcF-WS and no WCF-Custom